# "Biztalk projects" icon missing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk

I have Biztalk 2002 and Visual Studio 2003.
In Visual Studio I create a blank solution, I right click on the new solution to add a new project, which I want to select "Biztalk Projects". However, the BizTalk Projects selection is missing from my environment. 
Only C#, C++ Projects etc shows up.

I've also re-installed Biztalk 2002 (complete install, including tools for developers) but these Biztalk templates are still missing.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTS 2002 has it's own developer tools. It is not supported in VS 2003